# No connection between any variable and the result of the loss function

Tags: tensorflow.js

The optimizer I'm using isn't finding a connection between my variables and the loss function.

I'm new to machine learning in general and I'm trying to build a curve fitting application for the equation y = a * 2^(t/b). The trainable variables being "a" and "b". Right now I'm testing it with some synthetic data.

```
// Declare variables 
const a = tf.variable(tf.scalar(Math.random()));  
const b = tf.variable(tf.scalar(Math.random()));
const year = tf.tensor1d([1,2,3,4]);

//Declare optimizer
var optimizer = tf.train.sgd(learningRate);

// y = a * 2^(t/b)
function Moore(t){                      
var Moore_results = [];
aPrime = a.dataSync();
bPrime = b.dataSync();
tPrime = t.dataSync();
for(i = 0; i < tPrime.length; i++){
  Moore_results.push(aPrime * Math.pow(2,(tPrime[i]/bPrime)) );}
  const tensorMoore = tf.variable(tf.tensor1d(Moore_results));
  return tensorMoore;}

// Define loss function
function loss(predictions, labels) {
const meanSquareError = predictions.sub(labels).square().mean();
return meanSquareError;}

//Optimize loss function
optimizer.minimize(() => loss(Moore(year),year));
```

When I run the optimizer I get the error.

> Cannot find a connection between any variable and the result of the loss               >function y=f(x). Please make sure the operations that use variables are inside   >the function f passed to minimize().

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the use of `dataSync()` is the reason for this error. `dataSync()` is not recommended, even if we ignore the discussion about `optimizer.minimize()`. It downloads the values from GPU to CPU, which slows down everything. It seems to me that you can do without  it.

Comment: Thank you I think that worked. But why would dataSync() cause that error if all it would do is slow it down ?

Answer (score 0):

The optimizer tries to optimize a variable tensor created with `tf.variable` given the loss between the prediction and the expected value. You have to pass a prediction value as the following :

```js
function predict(t) {
  // y = a * 2 ^ (t / b)
  return tf.tidy(() => {
    return a.mul(tf.scalar(2)) // a * 2
      .pow(t.div(b)) // ^ (t / b)
  });
}

for (let iter = 0; iter < numIterations; iter++) {
  optimizer.minimize(() => {
    const predsYs = predict(xs);
    return loss(predsYs, ys);
  });
}
```

The optimizer will then compute the value of a and b that best predict your model